# XML Validation issue: error s4s-elt-must-match

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

I'm currently playing around with some basic XS Schema stuff, but am getting an irritating error when attempting to validate my schema. I'm using XMLValidation.com and the error I'm getting is:

```
s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'lecturers' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: element.
```

Then, my XSD is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="lecturers">
    <xs:element name="lecturer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="first" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="last" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="teaching">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="course" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="course" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="research" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:element>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The corresponding XML file reads like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lecturers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="lecturers.xsd"> 
   <lecturer>   
  <name title="Professor" first="Peter" last="Quirk" /> 
  <teaching> 
    <course code="CO3070">XML and the Web</course> 
    <course code="CO3300">Web Server Architectures</course> 
  </teaching> 
<research>The application of Web protocols to Biology</research> 
   </lecturer> 
</lecturers>
```

Anyone have any ideas why my code isn't validating and what I can do to sort it out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following to work...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="lecturers">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="lecturer">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="first" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="last" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element> <!-- name -->
            <xs:element name="teaching">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element name="course">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                      <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element> <!-- course -->
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element> <!-- teaching -->
            <xs:element name="research" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element> <!-- lecturer -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> <!-- lecturers -->
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

lecturers must contain complexType like you have for other elements :-

```
<xs:element name="lecturers">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="lecturer">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
```

...

The error, though cryptic, says so.

Answer (score 0):

To get the xml validated, this schema will do it.

```
<xs:element name="teaching">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="course" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent> 
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="research" type="xs:string"/>
```