# s4s-elt-must-match.1: error in xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm getting the following error while trying to validate a xml schema-

```
16: 24  s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'member' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: complextype.
31: 21  s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'intake' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: complextype.
```

Below is the schema-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="record">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="hof" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xs:element name="member" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complextype>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="age" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                                    <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="occupation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="pregnant" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="lactating" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:all>
                            </xs:complextype>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="intake" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complextype>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="food" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complextype>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                    <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:decimal" minInclusive="0" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complextype>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complextype>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And this is the corresponding XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<record xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com record.xsd">
    <id>
        <hof>ABC</hof>
        <member>
            <name>ABC</name>
            <age>35</age>
            <sex>Male</sex>
            <occupation>Manual Laboror</occupation>
        </member>
        <member>
            <name>DEF</name>
            <age>30</age>
            <sex>Female</sex>
            <occupation>House Wife</occupation>
            <pregnant>no</pregnant>
            <lactating>no</lactating>
        </member>
        <member>
            <name>ghi</name>
            <age>2</age>
            <sex>Female</sex>
        </member>
    </id>
    <intake>
        <food>
            <name>rice</name>
            <amount>800</amount>
        </food>
        <food>
            <name>dal</name>
            <amount>200</amount>
        </food>
    </intake>
</record>
```

I've already tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670153/xml-validation-issue-error-s4s-elt-must-match) but could'nt get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your schema document.  XML is case-sensitive, so all the occurrences of

```
<xs:complextype>
```

should be

```
<xs:complexType>
```

with a capital "T" (and likewise for the matching closing tags).